# Modern equivalent of javadeps?

Tags: java, command-line, dependencies, makefile

I am looking for a replacement for javadeps, which I used to use to generate sections of a Makefile to specify which classes depended on which source files.

Unfortunately javadeps itself has not been updated in a while, and cannot parse generic types or static imports.

The closest thing I've found so far is [Dependency Finder](http://depfind.sourceforge.net/).  It almost does what I need but does not match non-public classes to their source files (as the source filename does not match the class name.)  My current project has an interface whose only client is an inner class of a package-private class, so this is a significant problem.

Alternatively if you are not aware of a tool that does this, how do you do incremental compilation in large Java projects using command-line tools?  Do you compile a whole package at a time instead?

Notes:

1. javadeps is not to be confused with [jdepend](http://clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html), which is for a very different purpose.
2. This question is a rewrite of "[Tool to infer dependencies for a java project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170025/tool-to-infer-dependencies-for-a-java-project)" which seemed to be misunderstood by 2 out of 3 responders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the `<depend>` task in ant, which is ok, but not 100% trustworthy.  Supposedly [JavaMake](http://www.experimentalstuff.com/Technologies/JavaMake/index.html) can do this dependency analysis, but it seems to be rarely updated and the download page is only sometimes available.

Comment: Thanks.  Although JavaMake doesn't parse Java source it's probably the best match right now.